# Can I enforce monotonically increasing neural net outputs (min, mean, max)?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, tensorflow

Hi I'm using a DL model (TensorFlow) to predict daily minimum, mean, and maximum values of a target dataset. I was thinking that the model would have 3 outputs for each day, (min, mean, max).

Is there a clean way to **enforce** the correct order of these (i.e., min<mean<max)? I can add a penalty to encourage the model to train that way, but that seems like a bit of a work-around.

Comment: $a + b \sigma (X) $ for $b>0$ will always be at least as large as $a$, so you can structure the output to be non-decreasing. $\sigma$ can be the standard logistic function or any nonnegative, monotonic increasing function.

Comment: Interesting idea, @Sycorax. So lets say $y_{min} = a(X)$ then $y_{mean} = a + b\sigma(X)$ and $y_{max} = y_{mean} +c\sigma(X)$ and the model would output the $a$, $b$, and $c$, right? That certainly would make it monotonic. One potential problem is that $b$ and $c$ are the (mean-min) and (max-mean) *differences* and $a$ is an actual output, so there could be a scale issue. If I do a simple combination of losses from the three outputs, the loss from $a$ would likely be much larger than for $b$ or $c$ so the model would be biased toward getting $a$ accurate rather than $b$ or $c$, right?

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are fixed for all inputs, it's very plausible that disparate scales could be a problem. If $a,b,c$ are also functions of the individual sample, then perhaps this is mitigated, at the cost of higher complexity. What kind of bias exists and what direction it takes seems to depend on the loss function, the data, the model, and how the model is trained.

Comment: This could be achieved with custom recurrent layer, providing box plot values as an output, [Five number summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-number_summary).

Comment: @Galen Output of Five number summary, quantiles are monotonic.

Comment: @Galen Should be, with [BPTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation_through_time) with the numerical derivative for quantile functions.

Comment: Why do you care if your values aren't ordered?  I mean, if you just want to try to guess each without regard for consistency, then what's the harm in them lacking consistency?  Alternatively, if you _do_ value consistency, then presumably you want to focus on coming up with a model that captures the consistencies you want, then generate descriptions based on fits of that model.

Comment: Why do you want to enforce this? When you're training an English language model, you'll want it to output "e" more often than it outputs "q," but there's no need to force it to do that; it'll do that automatically. In any case, is it necessary to enforce this constraint _during training_ or is it sufficient to only enforce it after the fact? A lot of suggestions in this thread have the potential to hinder training.

Comment: @TannerSwett op doesn’t want to produce nonsensical output, e.g min=1 and mean =0

Answer (score 20):

Two techniques: penalty and variable transformation.

### penalty

build one model with these three outputs, then modify/customize the loss function during its estimation by adding the penalty for violation of the assumption. this will not guarantee the inequalities but will make them very unlikely.

You can simply add $-\lambda[\min(y_2-y_1,0)+\min(y_3-y_2,0)]$ where $\lambda$ is a hyper parameter reflecting how badly you want to enforce the conditions, and $y_1,y_2,y_3$ are you min, mean and max outputs. I’m using ReLU function here, but you can use any strictly positive function.

### variable transformation

I use this technique in similar situations. Here's how it goes. Create new variables: $$y'_1=y_2\\y'_2=\ln(y_2-y_1)\\y'_3=\ln(y_3-y_2)$$
Now you can fit the unconstrained model to new variables, then reconstruct the outputs as
$$y_2=y'_2\\y_1=y_2-e^{y'_2}\\y_3=y_2+e^{y'_3}$$
The outputs will be guaranteed to have the required conditions.
There are variations, e.g. you can transform min, mean and max into mean, range and mean/range etc which can be more stable. You can replace exponent with any strictly positive function such as ReLU, as it is noted in a comments.

This may look like a better technique, but it has its own issues. The main one is that fitting to logarithm can produce very wild forecasts. It's one reason why you should not transform the mean itself, and only min and max are transformed to distances from the mean. This way at least we may get reasonable mean forecast, and maybe crazy min and max, which are expected to be lousy anyways.

### related issue

Another thing to be aware of is that usually mean forecast should be expected to have lower variance than min and max. Therefore, you may make some accommodations in your loss function to allow min and max have larger forecast error than mean.

Comment: Regarding the penalty. If I'm calculating a _loss_ would it not be $\lambda(max(y_1-y_2, 0) + max(y_2 - y_3, 0))$? - I guess that's the same as yours it just returns positive values instead of negative.

Comment: you want the penalty be zero when $y_1<y_2$ and positive when the condition is broken. whichever function does this will work as a penalty function, try different ones

Comment: @jsad, you were right, I corrected the typo

Comment: A better choice instead of the exponential/logarithm substitution may be some soft-RELU flavour. $d \mapsto d - \tfrac1d$ has pretty nice properties, with inverse $e \mapsto \tfrac{e}2 + \sqrt{\tfrac{e^2}4 + 1}$.

Comment: What is the reason why soft-RELU might be better in this case?

Answer (score 5):

It may be infeasible to formally check the [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) for your optimization problem, however you can still try encoding your [inequality constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_optimization) as if the conditions hold. Then it is a matter of checking whether the training behaves nicely in practice.

If you're unfamiliar with encoding constraints into an objective function in the way that KKT states, see [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) for a first example with equality constraints. Then I recommend you look at encoding inequality constraints (see [example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/lagrange-multiplier-approach-with-inequality-constraints/)) in a similar fashion.

Once you have the mathematical expression in hand, you'll need to implement it in Tensorflow. You can build your own loss function class by inheriting from the [`tf.keras.losses.Loss`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Loss) base class.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in above discussion with @Galen:

**Conjecture** This might be achieved with custom recurrent layer. We could provide a box plot values as an output, i.e., [Five number summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-number_summary) as a monotonic output. Though, internals of recurrent layer is a design choice, see [Define custom LSTM Cell in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54231440/define-custom-lstm-cell-in-keras?noredirect=1&lq=1). Here, output of LSTM cell will be our monotonic summary function. This approach **guarantees** the inequality.

Comment: I really like this idea, but how would an LSTM **guarantee** inequality? So let's say an LSTM is outputting $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5$ where $y_i$ are the diff parts of the 5 number summary and, since it's recurrent, $y_2$ is a function of $y1$ and $y_3$ is a function of $y_2$, etc. If in the training data $y_1<y_2$ and $y_2 < y_3$ _always_, then the model _should_ learn that constraint, but is that actually **guaranteed**? ... Not saying it's not. I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Not LSTM itself but its output unit guarantees monotonic output, i.e., summary function. Model doesn't learn that function, output function  is hard-coded and "pools numbers from the buffer" (previous series within **custom** LSTM cell) and computes monotonic summary, which is guaranteed by definition.

Comment: Recurrent layers are for reading or writing sequences, aren't they? In your proposal, what sequence is the recurrent layer reading or writing?

Comment: @TannerSwett Sequence ("buffer") generated by the previous layer.

Comment: Are you saying that the recurrent layer should generate a sequence of numbers, and then a summary of that sequence should be taken and then used as the output?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you are better off investigating quantile regression.
see eg
https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-quantile-regression-in-tensorflow-1dbc792fe597.

What I believe you want is to predict the mean and limits of your distribution. at each x value.  using the minimum and maximum as targets will not give you what you want. instead you will have the expected value of the minimum/maximum at each input (this is what MSE produces).
eg input is x

| id | x | y_mean | y_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 5 |

then the prediction for y_max for input x=1 will be 3, not 5.

if instead you predict the quantiles you will get eg 10 percentile, 50 percentile and 90 percentile of your distribution.

(an alternative simpler way is to continue with mse,but predict the mean and squared error.  that gives you the variance and you can eg estimate the percentiles making a normal approximation)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood the question, here's a simple approach.

For outputs a b and c, you could enforce positive values for the second and third outputs via a suitable activation function, and then train to find values a b and c, such that a is the min, a + b is the mean, and a + b + c is the max value.

Answer (score 0):

Why not applying cumsum layer at the very end of your model?
By doing that, the model will predict the difference between t-1 and t on the layer n-1.

Something like:

```py
tf.math.cumsum(y_features, axis=time_series_axis_index)`
```